Unable to setup nativewind to function with expo SDK 52
I'm trying to set up NativeWind in a new project using Expo SDK 52, but the styles are not applying to my components. I've followed the setup instructions in the NativeWind documentation, but it still doesn't work.
Here are the steps I took:

Installed NativeWind and dependencies:
npm install nativewind tailwindcss react-native-reanimated react-native-safe-area-context


Initialized Tailwind CSS:
npx tailwindcss init


Added the following to my tailwind.config.js:
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
  content: ["app/index.js", "./App.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}", "./components/\*\*/\*. {js,jsx,ts,tsx}"],
  presets: [require("nativewind/preset")],
  theme: {
    extend: {},
  },
  plugins: [],
}



Added the following to my babel.config.js:
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: [
      ["babel-preset-expo", { jsxImportSource: "nativewind" }],
      "nativewind/babel"
    ],
  };   
};



Here is my package.json
{
"name": "capp",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "expo-router/entry",
"scripts": {
 "start": "expo start",
 "android": "expo start --android",
 "ios": "expo start --ios",
 "web": "expo start --web"
},
"dependencies": {
 "expo": "~52.0.11",
 "expo-constants": "~17.0.3",
 "expo-linking": "~7.0.3",
 "expo-router": "~4.0.11",
 "expo-status-bar": "~2.0.0",
 "nativewind": "^4.1.23",
 "react": "18.3.1",
 "react-native": "0.76.3",
 "react-native-reanimated": "^3.16.3",
 "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.12.0",
 "react-native-screens": "~4.1.0",
 "tailwindcss": "^3.4.16"
},
"devDependencies": {
 "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
},
"private": true
}

Here is my index.jsx
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import {  Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { Link } from  'expo-router'


export default function App() {
    return (
        <View className="flex-1 items-center justify-center bg-black">
            <Text>CAPP!</Text>
            <StatusBar style="auto" />
            <Link href="/profile " style={{ color: 'blue'}}>Go to Profile!</Link>
        </View>
    );
}

When I use Tailwind classes (e.g., className="bg-blue-500 p-4"), they don't seem to apply. I've also tried clearing the cache and restarting the development server.
What could be causing this issue? Are there additional setup steps required for NativeWind to work with Expo SDK 52?
I’ve followed the NativeWind setup instructions, including installing dependencies, configuring tailwind.config.js, and verifying the content paths. I’m using the className prop for styling but can’t get it to work. I’ve also tried clearing the cache and restarting the dev server, but no luck.

Any solution for this?

any luck ? i have the same problem

You need add 'metro.config.js' and, delete '.expo' file or run 'npx expo start --clear'

My issue turned out to be in the placement of my global.css file that was in the root instead of the app...that solved my issue..also check the path for the global.css file in the metro.config file..Also check the naming of the css file..metro config names it as global.css and i had it as globals.cssenter image description here

+1 to this fix. An AI tool that just checks naming consistence and nothing more may well worth millions.
